# asp:Repeater datasource with multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, repeater

I am working on a project to display website and payment errors. In SQL table which logs the errors there is are two columns which contains XML. In code I am parsing the XML into separate tables. So my setup is:

```
<Repeater ID="ParentRepeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <Label Text='<%#Eval("title")%>' />
        <Repeater ID="Child1" DataSource='<%#Eval("XMLTable1")%>' >
            <ItemTemplate>
               <Label Text='<%#Eval("CardType")%>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

I have set the DataSource for the parent repeater in code behind like so:

```
DataSet dsRepeaterSource = new DataSet();
DataTable dtSQLTable = new DataTable();
DataTable dtXMLTable1 = new DataTable();

dtXMLTable1.TableName = "XMLTable1";

dtSQLTable = SQLDataReader; // Copies Sql Table to DataTable
dtXMLTable1 = XML Table; // Copies XML table to DataTable

dsRepeaterSource.Tables.Add(dtSQLTable);
dsRepeaterSource.Tables.Add(dtXMLTable1);

ParentRepeater.DataSource = dsRepeaterSource;
```

The ParentRepeater now has a datasource with two tables. I am wondering how to use the multiple tables within the repeater. Any help is appreciated, thanks.